# How to increase cpu usage and performance in MVC or IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, loops, iis, model-view-controller

I have website and dedicated server for my website.

In my project there is 10^6 loop witch import record from xml file and finally save in database.

The for loop section is not fast as windows application version of this project.

the question is:

#### Q1: is there any way to increase cpu usage `for loop` section of my project?

#### Q2: is there any way to allow highly cpu usage in IIS for my website?

Thank you

Code:

```
foreach (var row in records)// about 150,000 record
{
    string cs = row.Field<string>("tsb");
    try
    {
        int rowCount = row.Table.Columns.Count - 6;


        string rowUserName = row.Field<string>("UserName").Trim();

        if (rowUserName != userName) 
        {
    task.taskStatus = (int)taskStatus.failed;
    task.details += Languages.Properties.Resources.task_eror_user_unique + ":" + cs; 
    TaskHelper.edit(task);
    return Json(new { success = false, message = Languages.Properties.Resources.task_eror_user_unique + ":" + cs }); 
        }


        long drh = Convert.ToInt32(row.Field<string>("drh"));

        var gm = db.gms.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(g => g.number == drh && g.id_gmState == 1);

        if (gm == null || gm.rowCount != rowCount)    
        {
    task.taskStatus = (int)taskStatus.failed;
    task.details += Languages.Properties.Resources.task_eror_gm_count + ":" + cs; 
    TaskHelper.edit(task);
    return Json(new { success = false, message = Languages.Properties.Resources.task_eror_gm_count + ":" + cs }); 
        }


        int ck = 0;
        int cj = 0;

        try
        {
    ck = Convert.ToInt32(row.Field<string>("_txtcodnakol"));
    cj = Convert.ToInt32(row.Field<string>("_txtcodnajoz"));
        }
        catch
        {
    task.taskStatus = (int)taskStatus.failed;
    task.details += Languages.Properties.Resources.task_erorr_code + ":" + cs; 
    TaskHelper.edit(task);
    return Json(new { success = false, message = Languages.Properties.Resources.task_erorr_code + ":" + cs });
        }


        if (db.Cards.AsNoTracking().Any(c => c.id_user == user.Id && c.cs == cs && c.id_gm == gm.id && c.ck == ck && c.cj == cj))
        {
    task.taskStatus = (int)taskStatus.failed;
    task.details += Languages.Properties.Resources.task_eror_card_unique + ":" + cs; 
    TaskHelper.edit(task);
    return Json(new { success = false, message = Languages.Properties.Resources.task_eror_card_unique + ":" + cs }); 
        }


        string value = "";
        string rowContent = gm.gmRow.gmRowTitles.FirstOrDefault()?.rowContent; 
        int countOption = Regex.Matches(rowContent, "ch=").Count;


        var coefficientValue = gm.CoefficientValues.Any() ? gm.CoefficientValues.FirstOrDefault().value : 1; 
        int realCost = 0;            

        for (int i = 1; i <= gm.rowCount; i++) // at least 15 rows
        {
    string option = row.Field<string>("j" + i);

    var distinctOption = option.Distinct().ToArray();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(option) || option.Length != distinctOption.Length)
    {
        task.taskStatus = (int)taskStatus.failed;
        task.details += Languages.Properties.Resources.task_error_option_null + ":" + i + ":" + cs;
        TaskHelper.edit(task);
        return Json(new { success = false, message = Languages.Properties.Resources.task_error_option_null + ":" + i + ":" + cs });
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < distinctOption.Length; j++)// under 4 count loop
    {
        int item = Convert.ToInt32(distinctOption[j].ToString());
        if (item < 1 || item > countOption)
        {
            task.taskStatus = (int)taskStatus.failed;
            task.details += Languages.Properties.Resources.task_error_option_null + ":" + i + ":" + cs;
            TaskHelper.edit(task);
            return Json(new { success = false, message = Languages.Properties.Resources.task_error_option_null + ":" + i + ":" + cs });
        }
    }

    for (int j = 1; j <= countOption; j++) // under 4 count loop
    {
        if (option?.Contains(j + "") ?? false)
            value += "1,";
        else
            value += "0,";
    }

    if (realCost == 0 && i == 1)
        realCost = 1;
    realCost *= (option.Length * coefficientValue);
        }

        long cost = Convert.ToInt32(row.Field<string>("tmvs")); 


        if ((realCost != cost && (realCost > gm.minCardValue)) || (realCost > gm.maxCardValue)) 
        {
    task.taskStatus = (int)taskStatus.failed;
    task.details += Languages.Properties.Resources.task_eror_card_cost_invalid + ":" + cs;
    TaskHelper.edit(task);
    return Json(new { success = false, message = Languages.Properties.Resources.task_eror_card_cost_invalid + ":" + cs }); 
        }

        if ((realCost != cost && (realCost <= gm.minCardValue))) 
        {
    if (cost != gm.minCardValue)
    {
        task.taskStatus = (int)taskStatus.failed;
        task.details += Languages.Properties.Resources.task_eror_card_cost_invalid + ":" + cs;
        TaskHelper.edit(task);
        return Json(new { success = false, message = Languages.Properties.Resources.task_eror_card_cost_invalid + ":" + cs }); 
    }
        }


        Card card = new Card
        {
    id_gm = gm.id,
    id_user = user.Id,
    id_cardStates = 1,
    value = value,
    Cost = cost,
    cj = cj,
    ck = ck,
    cs = cs
        };
        db.Cards.Add(card);

        progress += perPercent;
        if ((int)progress > task.percentCompleted)
        {
    task.percentCompleted = (int)progress;
    TaskHelper.edit(task);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        task.taskStatus = (int)taskStatus.failed;
        task.details += ex.InnerException + ":" + cs;
        TaskHelper.edit(task);
        return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.InnerException + ":" + cs });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you re-implementing your import routine, or are you referencing the existing assembly?

Comment: a) Do you mean that the loop is O(10^6)? b) Can you show us the code in question? There's not enough information here to debug this.

Comment: @kettch I import routine and the problem not in save state the problem is i want to increase speed of for clause. I want at least one core of my cpu use 80% of cpu power

Comment: You should rewrite your question. I can think of many ways to make your cpu usage 100%, if that's your goal but I don't think it is. Post some code so we can say something useful.

Comment: @EJoshuaS there is not any special for. its regular for clause and you can not remove any part of my code. I only want to use more cpu in my project

Comment: Please post the code so we can look at it and determine what is wrong.

Comment: What you're asking for would usually involve some kind of code change (using parallelism, asynchronous operations, etc.), and we can't really make recommendations on that without having actually seen the code in question. Also, please clarify what you mean by 10^6.

Comment: I cannot see what is the problem. Do you observe low CPU usage?

Comment: @LexLi I answered my question the problem is EF slow invoce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved 
The main problem was

```
db.Cards.Add(card);
```

This method invoked and give many times to add new card

In my new code i used

```
List<Card> listCard = new List<Card>();

listCard.add(card); //db.Cards.Add(card);
```

this increased my performance from `35 minutes` to `4 seconds`